# How do I make associated tables editable in the admin pages?

Tags: cakephp

There are two tables in our database that are important for this question. In Orders, we have the following fields:

```
ID, account_id, sale_id, site_id, pending, order_date
```

The other related table, orders_product_types, is an associative table that contains

```
order_id, product_id, quantity
```

Cake originally baked an admin page for orders that works just as you would expect. However, the client has requested that we add the ability to edit the quantity of each product associated with the sale on that same orders.admin_edit page, as well as see the products on the admin_view page. I have already managed to get the view page to display (albeit in an unpretty way) with the following code. To the controller, I added

```
$order = $this->Order->findById($id);
    $this->recursive = 1;
```

to the controller and included it in the set, and I display them on the view page with this:

```
<?php foreach ($order['ProductType'] as $productType){
            echo $productType['type'];
            echo $productType['OrdersProductType']['quantity'];?>
            <br></br>
            <?
        }?>
```

However, now I'm stuck on how to do this in the cake form for editing. Ideally, I would like to find a way to do this using proper cake functions, but I'm still new to this and am still figuring out how everything works. The pertinent part of the form that allows them to edit the information for the order looks like this:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Order'); ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo __('Edit Order'); ?></legend>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('id');
    echo $this->Form->input('account_id');
    echo $this->Form->input('sale_id');
    echo $this->Form->input('site_id');
    echo $this->Form->input('pay later');
    echo $this->Form->input('order_date');
    echo $this->Form->input('Coupon');
    echo $this->Form->input('ProductType');
?>
</fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
```

Ideally, I would like to find some way to follow this syntax, but to include fields from the associated table orders_product_types so that they can edit the quantities directly in this form. How would I include a second table within the cake structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find a way to do it "properly" with cake syntax like I was looking for, but I did eventually solve the problem by inserting a table in the view as follows:

```
<table>
    <? foreach($productTypes as $id => $productType):?>
    <tr class="product">
        <td><?= $productType ?></td>
        <td class="price" id="<?= $id ?>"></td>
        <td>        
            <select name="data[Quantity][<?=$id?>]" class="quantity">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td class="subtotal"></td>
    </tr>
    <? endforeach; ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4" style="text-align: right" id="total"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If anyone has a proper way to do it, please let me know. I am still learning my way around cake, and every little bit helps.